# XnUserID ROS source code

Tags: openi-tracker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While looking at the source code for openni_tracker.cpp, I came across a class called XnUserID. I cannot find the constructor for the class, and I have found nothing about it on the internet. Could someone post the constructor for XnUserID as well as its functions, or at least tell me where I can find it?

On a side note, what is Xn supposed to mean? It is in a lot of the code for ROS packages.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10457/xnuserid-ros-source-code/) by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 208 on 2011-07-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

XnUserIS is just an XnUInt32:

typedef XnUInt32 XnUserID

ref: http://www.ros.org/doc/api/nao_openni/html/XnTypes_8h_source.html

---

Originally posted by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) with karma: 753 on 2011-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Miguel Prada](https://answers.ros.org/users/164/miguel-prada/) on 2011-07-05**:
All the types that start with Xn are defined by the OpenNI framework. Check it's documentation and API to find out more.

**Comment by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on 2011-07-01**:
How can it be an unsigned int if it is its own class?

**Comment by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) on 2011-07-01**:
XnUInt32 is just an unsigned int

**Comment by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) on 2011-07-01**:
typedef unsigned int XnUInt32
ref: http://www.ros.org/doc/api/nao_openni/html/XnPlatformWin32_8h.html#a87b742cf4a64d1e312960b2f35614731

**Comment by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on 2011-07-01**:
Where can I find the definition for XnUInt32?